# Open a TabLayout as a child of Expandable list

Tags: android, parent-child, expandablelistview, android-tablayout

I am working on a project which demands to open a tablayout under the onclick of expandablelistview parent, means i want to open a tablayout as a child of expandablelistview. How can I implement such?

Comment: try adding what you tried up to now

Comment: I had tried OnGroupClickListener to do so but its not opening the layout @jagapathi

Comment: try to post your code